# IIS7 returns 403.1 (execute access denied) for image file

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, network-share

I have a web app running in IIS7 on Windows Server 2008. There is a virtual directory pointing to a shared folder "/Content/Data" on another machine (running Windows Server 2003), as well as a real directory "/Content/Images" on the local machine (web app sub folder).

Accessing images in "/Content/Images" is no problem, but **when an image (e.g. a JPEG file) in the "/Content/Data" is accessed by a browser, IIS returns this error:**

> HTTP Error 403.1 - Forbidden: Execute
>   access is denied.

However, the web app can read and write to / from it. I assume IIS and ASP.NET are running under different user accounts?

Does anyone have an idea on what I have to do to make it work? I have set the permissions on the shared folder to Everyone Full Control, with no luck.

Comment: What happens if you turn on execute script permissions for the virtual directory?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something has configured IIS to map the `.jpg` file type to an executable (could be .NET, CGI, ISAPI, ...).

Check, for the root of the IIS Web App, the Handler Mappings for a path that will match the URL of the file you are requesting.

(The error is about IIS being configured to not allow code to run to satisfy the HTTP request. One could create a handler for `*jpg` to allow the images to be generated dynamically or loaded from a database rather just serving static files.)

Comment: Since there is no problem with the images in the local "/Content/Images", I don't think this is the problem. They would not have worked either then, right?

Comment: @Kristoffer: not necessarily - the handler mappings can be specified at the site level, and at the directory level - check both places. Also, check the "MIME Types" settings in both places - make sure the .jpg/.jpeg is set to image/jpeg

Comment: @Kristoffer: General rule of finding problems: if you assume something must be working, it will be your assumption that is wrong. Checking doesn't take long.